# Flash сохранить контент по ссылке, а затем передать его по другой

Tags: flash, http

Допустим есть встроенный Flash объект на сайте. Возможно ли выполнить следующий порядок действий:
 1. Передать ему какой-нибудь конкретный URL;
 2. он сохраняет контент (около 10 мб.) в память;
 3. затем передаёт этот контент на другой адрес.

?

Answer (score 1):

Политика безопасности плеера не даст ему это сделать. Сервер сидящий на URL, должен обязательно выдать файл Crossdomain.

http://uppod.ru/talk_189

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html

http://quarantine.ucoz.ru/blog/crossdomain_xml_i_flash/2010-10-15-7

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html